# How can I fix this Logic Error within a Class Function?

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm making a Text Based RPG game for a university project and I have come across a logic error -- I believe it's a logic error because it doesn't produce the results I'm expecting.

I was designing a Turn-Based System and I wanted an automated function to match the Enemies' level with the Player's level and make it higher by 2. So, independently of whatever level the player is, this function will match the enemy's level and be 2 levels above.

This code looks like the following:

```
#ifndef ADD_H
#define ADD_H
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>


unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);

using namespace std;




class Character
   {
private:
/*
 * The UNDERSCORE is mainly so you know it's private!
*/
string _name;

int _level;
int _health;
int _hpThres;
int _exp;
int _expThres;
int _bonusDEF; // UNUSED
int _bonusATK; // UNUSED
int _totalATK; // UNUSED
int _attack;
int _damageMin;
int _damageMax;
int _defense;

public:
    Character();
    Character(const string name);
    virtual ~Character();

//Functions

void init (const string name);
string getAsString();


// THIS THE FUNCTION I'M CURRENTLY HAVING TROUBLES WITH
void levelMatch(int lvl)
{
    this->_level = lvl + _level;
}

//The functions below have the same format and they work, but the one above simply doesn't
void setBonus(int n, int m)
    {
    this->_attack = _attack + n;
    this->_defense = _defense + m;
    }

void levelUp(int exp)
    {
    while (this->_exp >= this->_expThres)
        {
        this->_exp -= this->_expThres;
        this->_level++;
        this->_expThres = (_level*100) - 50;
        }
    }

void damage(int dmg)
    {
     this->_health = _health -= dmg;
    }



//Accessors
inline const string& getName() const {return this->_name;}
inline const int& getLevel() const {return this->_level;}
inline const int& getHealth() const {return this->_health;}
inline const int& getHPThres() const {return this->_hpThres;}
inline const int& getEXP() const {return this->_exp;}
inline const int& getEXPThres() const {return this->_expThres;}
inline const int& getAttack() const {return this->_attack;}
inline const int& getDamageMin() const {return this->_damageMin;}
inline const int& getDamageMax() const {return this->_damageMax;}
inline const int& getDefense() const {return this->_defense;}


//Modifiers



};

#endif
```

This is where I use the function in the Main file: bellow there's the top half which is fine, it's the bottom half that I have an issue with.

```
#include "add.h"
#include <climits>

///TOP HALF OF MY CODE
void setName()
{

    // In case you forget, which you will, to print something from a class
    // Make an object class, using <CLASS NAME> OBJECT (INITIALIZE VARIBLE);
    // Now, since this is not yet optimized, other stats need to be initialized independently,
    // So, <CLASS OBJECT> SET FUNCTION (THE VARIABLE) will give that object that value,
    // To print it use: <CLASS OBJECT>.GET FUNCTION(); 
    // IMPORTANT NOTE: The GET FUNCTION is the value you need here. If you need to calculate something,
    // use the the GET FUNCTION by calling the Class Object (dot) GET FUNCTION.

    string name;

    cout << "Enter the name of your character: ";
    cin >> name;
    Character user (name);


}

void pressAnyKey(void)
    {
    cout << "\nPress ENTER to continue...";
    cin.ignore();
    }


//Above you can find amazing functions that you needed for future reference



int main()
{ 

    string YN;  // Sigh...

    cout << " \n";
    cout << "*****************************************" << endl;
    cout << "*                                       *" << endl;
    cout << "*   SECOND BRAVES: THE WAR BELL TOLLS   *" << endl;
    cout << "*                                       *" << endl;
    cout << "*****************************************\n";
    pressAnyKey();

    string name;

    cout << "Enter the name of your character: ";
    cin >> name;
    Character user (name);

    //cout << print the story 
    sleep(1);

    //Right so the section below may look intimidating, but let me explain
    //The Do-While Switch Loop is to increment two loops,
    //The main loop is the first you see, while has the option to choose the weapons,
    //The second is morer about whether you want said-weapon. 
    //The second loop will break when you respond Yes or No.
    //Saying Yes will break both loops as I have instructed,
    //Saying No will sent the user back to the main loop (with the "goto" command).
    //The Cin.fail doesn't seem to work as I wanted to, but it does the important bit,
    //which is to prevent the loop from going beserk if the user is stupid
    do
    {
    again:   
    int weapon;
    cout << "\nChoose your weapon: " << endl;
    cout << "************" << endl;
    cout << "*          *" << endl;
    cout << "* 1. Sword *" << endl;
    cout << "* 2. Axe   *" << endl;
    cout << "* 3. Lance *" << endl;
    cout << "*          *" << endl;
    cout << "************" << endl;

    cin >> weapon;

    while (cin.fail()) //Meant to catch the wrong type and ignore it
        {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, 1);
        cin.get();
        }

    switch(weapon)
      {

        case 1:
        {   
           cout << "This is the Hero Sword," << endl;
           cout << "Very high on Attack, but low on Defense!\n";
           cout << "Do you want to choose this weapon? (Y/N)" << endl;
           cin >> YN;

           if (YN == "Y")
               {
                int A = 3;
                int D = 1; 
                user.setBonus(A,D);

                cout << "You chose the Hero Sword!" << endl;

                break;
               }
           else
               {
                goto again;
               }

         }

        case 2:
            {
            cout << "This is the Hero Axe," << endl;
            cout << "It has balanced Attack and Defense!\n";
            cout << "Do you want to choose this weapon? (Y/N)" << endl;
            cin >> YN;

           if (YN == "Y")
               {
               int A = 2;
               int D = 2; 
               user.setBonus(A,D);

               cout << "You chose the Hero Axe!" << endl;

                break;
               }
           else
               {
                goto again;
               }
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            {
            cout << "This is the Hero Lance," << endl;
            cout << "Very high Defense, but low on Attack!\n";
            cout << "Do you want to choose this weapon? (Y/N)" << endl;
            cin >> YN;

           if (YN == "Y")
               {
               int A = 2;
               int D = 2; 
               user.setBonus(A,D);

               cout << "You chose the Hero Lance!" << endl;

                break;
               }
           else
               {
                goto again;
               }

            }

        default:
            {
             cout << "\nChoose a weapon, BASED ON THE NUMBERS AVAILABLE!" << endl;
             goto again;
            }
        } 
    } while (YN != "Y");
```

/// BOTTOM HALF of the code where my issue resides

```
        string N1;
        N1 = "Shadow Armour";
        Character Enemy1 (N1);
        Enemy1.levelMatch(user.getLevel() + 2); // Doesn't work.
        sleep(1);

        do
        {
        back:
        int choice;
        cout << "A wild " << Enemy1.getName() << " is challenging you to battle!" << endl;
        sleep(1);
        cout << "What do you want to do?" << endl;
        cout << "*      1. Attack      *" << endl;
        cout << "*      2. Guard       *" << endl;
        cout << "*      3. Brave       *" << endl;
        cout << "*      4. Run         *" << endl;
        cout << "***********************" << endl;
        cout << "* " << user.getName() << ": " << user.getHealth() << " Hit Points left!" << endl;
        cout << "***********************" << endl;
        cout << "* " << Enemy1.getName() << ": " << Enemy1.getHealth() << " Hit Points left!" << endl;
        cout << "***********************" << endl;

        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
            {

            case 1:
                {
                int BattleDamage;
                int RandomDamage = rand() % (user.getDamageMin() - user.getDamageMax() + 1) + user.getDamageMin();
                BattleDamage = Enemy1.getHealth() + Enemy1.getDefense() - RandomDamage;
                Enemy1.damage(BattleDamage);
                cout << "You attacked the monster! You did " << BattleDamage << " of damage!" << endl;

                break;
                }
            case 2:
                cout << "ye" << endl;
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "ye" << endl;
                break;
            case 4:
                cout << "ye" << endl;
                break;
            default:
                {
                cout << "\nChoose an option, BASED ON THE NUMBERS AVAILABLE!" << endl;
                goto back;
                }

            }
        } while (user.getHealth() > 0);


}
```

The add.cpp file:

```
#include "add.h"
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

Character::Character() 
{

}

Character::Character(const string name)
{
    this->_name = name;

    this->_level = 1;
    this->_health = this->_level+16;
    this->_hpThres = this->_level+16;
    this->_exp = (this->_level*100)-50;
    this->_expThres = (this->_level*100)-50;
    this->_attack = (this->_level+3);
    this->_defense = round((_level+2)*1.5);
    this->_damageMin = this->_attack-2;
    this->_damageMax = this->_attack+2;

}

Character::~Character() 
{

}




//Functions
//void Character::init(const string name){ }

string Character::getAsString()
    {

    }
```

I know it doesn't work because the calculation should make the Enemy Hit Points higher by 2, but when it's compiled and it runs, the Enemy's Hit Points are same as the Player, meaning the function never worked in the first place.

Output from running the code:

```
A wild Shadow Armour is challenging you to battle!
What do you want to do?
*      1. Attack      *
*      2. Guard       *
*      3. Brave       *
*      4. Run         *
***********************
* a: 17 Hit Points left!
***********************
* Shadow Armour: 17 Hit Points left! <-- This should have been 19, not 17.
```

Being 17 means the function was ignored and never worked.

I'm new to C++, so I understand if my code looks bad.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I didn't execute your code, but from what I read, you update the enemy's level in `levelMatch` but don't update the health accordingly (this is only done in the constructor, not in `levelMatch`)

Comment: A remark about the coding style: in member functions, you don't have to use `this->`; instead you can directly access member variables.

Comment: Coding style:  search the internet for "StackOverflow c++ leading underscore".  To avoid conflicts, use underscores at the end of identifiers.

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to single step through your code *watching* values of variables.  Often, using a debugger is faster than posting correctly to StackOverflow and *waiting* for somebody to inspect your code or debug your code for you.

Comment: When you used the debugger, which statement is causing the issue?

Comment: @Caninonos Okay, I followed your tip and it worked. I will now update the rest of my code to meet the criteria. Thank you, good sir.

Comment: @Flopp Thanks for the tips, I will certainly apply this from now on.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks for the comments, Thomas. I hadn't debugged it because my University wants me to use this god-awful online IDE and the debugger is still in beta, so I didn't try my chances. I managed to find a solution, but thank you anyway.